# change the background image of a view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a class of keyboard like this:

```
@implementation Testkeyboard 

 -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"FrameLetters2.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];  
 }
```

I want to create some methods to change the background *image like this

```
  -(void) changeImage1

  -(void) changeImage2
```

How it can be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might run into problems having not provided the code you've tried to implement them yourself and specific issues you're facing.

Comment: ravindra's answer will work for you. you should try it.

Answer (score 10):

Use `colorWithPatternImage` method like this

```
-(void) changeImage1
{
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIcolor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]];
}
-(void) changeImage2
{
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIcolor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar case and i think the easiest way is by adding a UIImageView to the view and make it fill the whole view area.

Comment: That is true. Create a new UIImageView and make it changed is much easier. Thanks

Comment: no need to change the view hierarchy for that and have overlapping siblings. I'd go with ravindra's approach